# How to insert java.util.Date object holding date and time into mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, java.util.date

I am using following code to insert a `java.util.Date` object in MySQL. `d1` is date object I'm getting from a function.  I tried casting `java.util.Date` into `java.sql.Date` but this doesn't save the time part.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO abc " +
              "VALUES" + "('Zara',?)";
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setDate(1, d1);
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Any Idea to store Date and time of Date Object in MySQL?

Comment: Use `setTimestamp(new Timestamp(date.getTime()))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert `java.util.Date` instance to `java.sql.Date` format. and then use it with PreparedStatement.

Change:

```
pstmt.setDate( 1, d1 );
```

to:

```
pstmt.setDate( 1, new java.sql.Date( d1.getTime() );
```

If the field is of type `datetime` or `timestamp`, you have to use

```
pstmt.setTimestamp( 1, new java.sql.Timestamp( d1.getTime() );
```

Comment: java.sql.Date doesn't hold any time part. It's limited to year, month and day. The OP even said it in his question.

Comment: Is there any way to store time part of java.util.Date Object?

Comment: @cks The second part of this answer explains how.

Comment: When using util date object to convert into sql timestamp you will not be getting any time part. you need to add explicitly. are just change your sql to use `now()` unless it is a manual input.